# Show Window without activating (keep application below it active)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I need to show a window (without title bar) above third party applications without my window taking focus.

I have tried using an `NSPanel` and setting enabling non-activating, but that didn't help.

I tried `orderFront:self`, but that didn't help either.

I always needed to add `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];` because the window wouldn't show otherwise.

I have here a sample project for just this functionality:
http://users.telenet.be/prullen/TopW2.zip

`UIElement` is set to `true` in the application's plist file, so there is no dock. You can activate the window by pressing `ALT + SPACE` at the same time. You will see that the app below it looses focus. Any thoughts on how to fix this? I've seen other apps do it so I know it's possible.

Edit: here's the code so far. Remember the window is a non-activating NSPanel.
I still need that last `NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps` line or otherwise it doesn't display. But of course that makes the window the active one.

```
 _windowController = [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindowController"];

    [[_windowController window] setLevel:NSNormalWindowLevel+1];
    [[_windowController window] orderFrontRegardless];

    [_windowController showWindow:self];

   [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

I've also subclassed NSPanel and added two methods:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow
{
    return YES;
}
```

Edit: OK, unchecking setHidesOnDeactivate fixes this, but now the window will never hide. I need it to hide when the user presses the app below it or switches to another app.

Edit 2: OK, this seems to fix the above issue:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideWindow) name:NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification object:nil];
}
- (void)hideWindow {
    [self setHidesOnDeactivate:YES];
}
```

Not sure if there's a better way.

And for those that want to know how to display the window:

```
    [[_windowController window] setLevel:NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel];
    [[_windowController window] orderFrontRegardless];
    [[_windowController window] makeKeyWindow];

    [_windowController showWindow:self];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either one of these should do the trick:

- Use `-[NSWindow orderFrontRegardless]` to get a normal level window to the front without activating the corresponding app, or
- Use `-[NSWindow setLevel:]` to increase the window level to something higher than `NSNormalWindowLevel`

Comment: thanks, unfortunately this still doesn't work. I still need to add the  activateIgnoringOtherApps:true call, otherwise it doesn't show. And that call of course makes it the active window.

Comment: @Wesley Uncheck "Hide on Deactivate" for the panel in your NIB.

Comment: Thanks, why didn't I think of that? That option, together with orderFrontRegardless and setLevel make it work, finally. Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell me though, how do I hide the window on deactivate? Since I do want it hidden if the user clicks on the app below it (or switches to another app).

Comment: If you want to do this after the user has actually interacted with your window, making it key, (and then clicks elsewhere), using an NSWindowDelegate should work. Close/hide the window when you get a `windowDidResignKey:` message.

Comment: thank you @puzzle, disabling `setHidesOnDeactivate` and using `windowDidResignKey` to call `NSApp.hide` fixed the problem! After that I just call `makeKeyAndOrderFront` and `orderFrontRegardless` to bring it back. To hide the app programmatically I use: `window.resignKey`

Answer (score 1):

Not to take away from @puzzle's useful answer, but it sounds like your problem has something to do with using an `NSPanel` instead of an `NSWindow`.

The "How Panels Work" docs say:

> - Onscreen panels, except for alert dialogs, are removed from the screen when the application isn’t active and are restored when the application again becomes active. This reduces screen clutter.
> - Specifically, the NSWindow implementation of the hidesOnDeactivate method returns NO, but the NSPanel implementation of the same method returns YES.

So perhaps you could override `hidesOnDeactivate` to return NO, or change to `NSWindow`

Comment: I think the problem is in the NIB, hideOnDeactivate is checked there.

Comment: I've unchecked hide on deactivate, but now the panel never hides. Not when I click the app below it, not when I switch to another app. any ideas?

Comment: 9 years later, `hidesOnDeactivate = false` fixed the issue for me when building a small spotlight-like app :)  thanks!