# How to show a window without stealing focus on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I was wondering how could spotlight floating with focus, and another window still has focus!

[image]

I could easy make a window floating over all other window with `window?.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.maximumWindow))`,but I cannot let two windows both has focus, help!

Is there any function like `ShowWithoutActivating` in Cocoa?

Comment: What do you mean "both has focus"? That's not possible. If it were, then your typing would go to both windows, which would be very confusing and troublesome. The Spotlight window absolutely "steals" focus. (I wouldn't really consider it "stealing", since it was requested by the user.)

Comment: You might want to look at [Create Spotlight-like window in Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054473/create-spotlight-like-window-in-swift-4).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've been playing around with this a bit, and I seem to be able to produce this effect when the frontmost window is not from the same process as the frontmost application, which is what I suspect Spotlight is probably doing. I can achieve this like so:

1. Set LSUIElement to YES in my app's Info.plist.
2. In Interface Builder, set the window's class to NSPanel, check "Non Activating" in the Attributes Inspector, and set "isFloatingPanel" to YES in the User Defined Runtime Attributes under the Identity Inspector.
3. During some time that some other application is in front (I just used a 5-second delay to give myself time to pop some other app to the front and select a text field), call `makeKeyAndOrderFront()` followed by `orderFrontRegardless()` on the window.

When I do this, I get the following (note the focus ring still drawn on Xcode's "Module" field):

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That`s what I want.  And your answer is very clear, Truly grateful for your help.

Comment: Do give the focus back to the previous app I needed to grab which app was active (`NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications.first(where: {$0.isActive})`), stop text field from being first responder (`win.makeFirstResponder(nil)`), then call `activeApp?.activate(options: NSApplication.ActivationOptions.activateAllWindows)` to make the app have focus again.

Comment: How to make it work with "Hide on deactivate" option. After it is hid, I'm not able to bring it back. It works without this option. Only with `activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` but it steals focus :(

Comment: I have found a solution. I had to disable this option and code some workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077471/show-window-without-activating-keep-application-below-it-active#comment112101726_15079362

Comment: I personally had to add in `window.becomeKey()` for my NSPanel() to get it to take focus the way Spotlight does

Comment: In response to @DanielCompton - I just used `window.resignKey()`. This gives focus to the previously focused view

Comment: MacOS noob here, where do I find the window in IB to change its class? Also, how would I do this for an NSPopover?

Comment: @tyirvine [Never call this method directly.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621618-resignkey)

Answer (score 0):

There are two key conditions:

1. Use `NSPanel` as window
2. Add `.nonactivatingPanel` to `NSPanel`'s `styleMask`

```
let window = NSPanel(
    contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 800),
    styleMask: [
        .nonactivatingPanel,
        .titled,
        .closable,
        .miniaturizable,
        .resizable,
        .fullSizeContentView
    ],
    backing: .buffered,
    defer: false
)
```

Comment: The window that was activated and key does not receive events afterwards. This is not sufficient.