# Cocoa & Swift. How to show window without deactivating other window

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have my `UIElement` set to `YES` in `Info.plist`. Then I registered a hotkey. When it's pressed, it calls a `NSWindowController` object and shows a window.

But I must call `NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` after `mainWindowController.showWindow(self)` , causing any other windows blur.

I want to create a window that does not change other window's status but can focus on (or receive local keyboard events), **like what Alfred or Spotlight does.**

[image: Screenshot 1]

When Alfred is called out, Chrome does not blur. When I hit my keyboard, I typed in Alfred instead of Chrome's input field.

[image: Screenshot 2]

When I press `[ESC]`, Alfred hides. Chrome keeps activated and the text field is still focused on.

Comment: What is your NSWindow's [style mask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow.stylemask)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show a window without stealing focus on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023769/how-to-show-a-window-without-stealing-focus-on-macos)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for, thank you. This can be marked as duplicated.