# Create Spotlight-like window in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos-mojave

I want to create a window as part of my app which is displaying a Spotlight-like window after hitting a certain keystroke.

[image]

But all I got is to hide the `title`:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    self.view.window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
    self.view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    self.view.window?.styleMask.insert(.fullSizeContentView)
}
```

Which results in:

[image]

How can I create such a view with Xcode 10 and Swift?

Comment: I have a library I've created for a similar window in one of my apps - [OpenQuickly](https://github.com/lukakerr/OpenQuickly) that you may find of use.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom window using NSPanel

```swift
final class Panel: NSPanel {
    init(contentRect: NSRect, backing: NSWindow.BackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {
        super.init(contentRect: contentRect, styleMask: [.titled, .resizable, .closable, .fullSizeContentView], backing: backing, defer: flag)
        
        self.isFloatingPanel = true
        self.level = .floating
        self.collectionBehavior.insert(.fullScreenAuxiliary)
        self.titleVisibility = .hidden
        self.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        self.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
        self.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        self.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
        self.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
        self.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
    }
    
    // `canBecomeKey` and `canBecomeMain` are required so that text inputs inside the panel can receive focus
    override var canBecomeKey: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override var canBecomeMain: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

and use it in `AppDelegate` like this:

```swift
final class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
   lazy var panel: NSPanel = FloatingPanel(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 700, height: 320),
        backing: .buffered,
        defer: false
    )

   func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // panel.contentView = ...
        panel.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        panel.center()
   }
}
```