# how to imlement a search bar like spotlight & alfred search bar

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

### Expected implementation style

More precisely, I want to implement something like a floating panel in `MacOS`, it won't cause current window loose focus, just appear silently and close silently like search bar of spotlight or alfred.

I thought the `NSPanel` may have properties to achive that, but after a few days exploring, i didn't make it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Create Spotlight-like window in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054473/create-spotlight-like-window-in-swift-4)

Comment: I have tried that answer, it do have a spotlight-like style, but the point is it takes the system focus, which is not exactly the same as spotlight. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Here is the answer [how-to-show-a-window-without-stealing-focus-on-macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023769/how-to-show-a-window-without-stealing-focus-on-macos)