# Make macOS window capture hover events even if set _setPreventsActivation:true and canBecomeKeyWindow:true

Tags: macos, nswindow, nspanel

I want to achieve a certain window behavior for a macOS app. I subclassed `NSWindow` to be able to add additional properties. So far, it works well with almost all requirements (dragging it, clicking buttons) while preserving the core requirement of *not making the currently active app **losing** focus.* What does not work is making the window's UI elements react to mouse-hover events.

**Requirements:**

- ☑️ Don't activate the app when showing the window → `_setPreventsActivation:true`
- ☑️ Prevent activation of the app when interacting with the window (click/drag) → `_setPreventsActivation:true`
- ﹖Make the window react to *mouse hover* events over interactive UI elements without activating the app

An example of an application that does very much what I intend to do (UX-wise) is 1Password. Here is a short clip: [An animated GIF showing 1Password UX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrb1z.gif)

Can someone explain what they likely do to make their window behave this way?

Comment: Is the window in the GIF a background window? Where does the keyboard input go? Is the question how to monitor global mouse events, how to recognize mouse-hover or how to implement a floating window?

Comment: Hey @Willeke, it is not a background window. Or how would I know? It "feels" exactly how spotlight would react. 

- The keyboard input should continue to go the active window ("should not take key"). In the shown example, 1Pass obviously takes key. 
- The question is which window properties are needed / which (private?) macOS APIs to invoke on an `NSWindow` in order to achieve the listed requirements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show a window without stealing focus on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023769/how-to-show-a-window-without-stealing-focus-on-macos)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had already been there - and could replicate the feature. What's missing is how to have these windows still taking hover events.

Comment: SwiftUI or AppKit?