# How to create a Qt window on macOS that stays on top without stealing focus?

Tags: macos, qt

I'm trying to create a Qt window on macOS that stays on top of other windows without stealing focus from other applications (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023769/how-to-show-a-window-without-stealing-focus-on-macos)). I have tried using Qt::Tool and WA_ShowWithoutActivating, however, the window still steals focus when it is shown.