# How to make a window behave like an input method or spotlight

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nspanel

How can I make a panel behave like e.g. Spotlight

[image]

or the input method

[image]

such that

- the window does not activate the app
- the window does close editors of other windows
- the window receives keyboard input
- closing/hiding the window does not hide the entire app (settings window may be open)

Tried the suggestions in

- [How to show a window without stealing focus on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023769/how-to-show-a-window-without-stealing-focus-on-macos)
- [Show Window without activating (keep application below it active)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077471/show-window-without-activating-keep-application-below-it-active#comment112101726_15079362)

But none of them achieves the same behavior.